# Do $\limsup A_n$ and $\liminf A_n$ always have probability 1 or 0?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Is it right that, for a sequence of events $(A_n)_{n}$, $\limsup A_n$ and $\liminf A_n$ have probability $1$ or $0$?\
My idea for $\limsup$ is for example the following:
$$P(\limsup A_n) = \mathbb{E}(I_{\limsup A_n}) = \mathbb{E}(\limsup I_{A_n})$$ and, since $I_{A_n}\in\{0,1\}$, the latter should be $0$ or $1$.

($I_{\{.\}}$ denotes the indicator function and I used the equality $\limsup I_{A_n} = I_{\limsup A_n}$)

Comment: No, try $A_n=A_1$ for every $n$, with $P(A_1)$ in $(0,1)$.

Comment: So what's wrong with my equality? Do I need more assumptions?

Comment: Yeah: independence.

Comment: Relevant: [Borel-Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel–Cantelli_lemma), (partial) [converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result).